# How to Integrate Apache Phoenix with laravel or PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, hadoop, apache-phoenix

I am building an app which has almost 65 million writes a day. The team has been struggling with Mysql, Maria DB. And its a huge requirement that we use RDBMS.

I am exploring Apache Phoenix which meets my requirement perfectly. Want to understand how to implement with Laravel 5.5

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/68980/how-to-query-hbase-via-php-script.html

Answer (score 0):

This is important; that you want to use the language that is native to Phoenix (Java).  In my opinion, you should use a Apache Thrift (Java) Query Service that queries the Phoenix Query Servers natively, and use a PHP client to connect to the Thrift service. That way, you can upgrade Phoenix whenever you want, and the Java service will continue to service request from a decoupled php client.